# UDP packets missing while receiving images

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am using UDP protocol to transfer images between monitor and device.I splitted the images into bytes and sending. In device side bytes received with loss.Some UDP packets gets lost.
So when rearranging the image, it becomes blur and some times mixed up.

My question is,

While rearranging the bytes how to fill the image with empty bytes. (Fill the missed bytes with empty packets).So that the missing sequences are shown as white space.

How to do that.??

Answer (score 0):

Which image format are you sending?  I suspect that in a compressed image there is no way to know how many pixels were lost.

What you could do instead is to dissect the image and compress those tiles and send the compressed tiles.  That way when you rebuild the image you know exactly which tiles are missing e.g. think google maps.

Comment: i HAVE A SEQUESNCES FOR EACH PACKETS SENDING AND RECEIVING.SO I CAN KNOW WHICH PACKETS ARE MISSED AND ALSO ITS SIZE

Comment: Also i am sending a jpg image.Also what is that tiles.i didn't hear about that.any reference sites?

Comment: To fix the image you need to know it size in pixels, not bytes. A tile is a like a tile on the floor.  The floor is made up of many tiles which join together to cover the floor.  BTW SHOUTING DOESN'T MAKE YOU LOOK ANY SANER. ;)

Comment: Ok.while sending as bytes through packets,how to know the pixel of that missing byte.but i know how many bytes are missed

Comment: By using the protocol that you are going to have to acquire or write.

Comment: You need to select portions of the image and send those portion as images you can rebuild.  If you don't get a portion, you replace that with all white.  A smarter way is to send one packet which has the average colour for each portion i.e. a low resolution copy which fits in a packet.  This was you can replace a missing portion with something which looks like the bit that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use TCP.**  If you need 100% correct reception, in order and intact, it's not a candidate application for UDP.

Comment: First i used TCP only.But it is very slow.Thats why i go with UDP.It is very fast compare to TCP